# Use a div as a background-image

Tags: css

I have a CSS class as follows:

```
.tree span.folder { 
    background: url(images/folder.gif) 4px 2px no-repeat; 
    cursor:pointer; 
    border:1px dotted #fff; 
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

This class gives a div a background image of a folder, which sits to the left in the div... but it could be anything.

With the advent of things like Font Awesome et al where they have built in icons which can be called as classes on their own, the need for **some** small icon style images goes away.

So, question is, if I have a premade class `.fa-folder` can I use that as the background image of another class or somehow combine it to give the result same as above class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but it is possible to apply the same css attributes to different selectors. `.fa-folder, .tree span.folder {...}`

Comment: Or is your question more like, "can I use a character from a font for a background, rather than an image file"?